# How to lower AD inter-site replication interval below 15 minutes?

Tags: active-directory, replication

When configuring Active Directory inter-site replication, there is a lower limit of 15 minutes for the replication interval; or at least, this limit is enforced by the AD Sites & Services console.

Is there any way to configure the inter-site replication interval for  site link to a lower value?

---

N.B. I know I could just place al DCs in the same site, which would enforce continuous replication; but I want to have proper AD sites in place, the requirement is to actually *lower the inter-site replication interval*.

Comment: You can do on change? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/canberrapfe/2012/03/25/active-directory-replication-change-notification-you/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not posible to set lower limit less then 15 min, but if you have good link you can enable notifications on site link. It will speed up change propagation between linked sites.

To do it for link:

1. Open ADSIEdit.msc.
2. In ADSI Edit, open `Configuration` container.
3. Expand Sites, navigate to the `Inter-Site Transports` container, and select object `CN=IP`.
4. Right-click the site link object for the sites where you want to enable change notification and select **Properties**.
5. In the **Attribute Editor** tab, double click on options attribute. Add 1 to it's value (if not defined - simply set `1`)
6. Click **OK**.

[More detailes about notifications](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/canberrapfe/2012/03/25/active-directory-replication-change-notification-you/).